# Error trying to read a file in scrapy

Tags: python, scrapy

I am trying to read a file which contains a list of domains to crawl. The results are added to a file(filename corresponding to the domain). When I try to run the code scrapy crawl apple

It throws an error:

```
def __init__(self)                 
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

domain.txt contains: anything.com hello.com

This is my code.

```
from scrapy.contrib.spiders import CrawlSpider, Rule
from scrapy.contrib.linkextractors.sgml import SgmlLinkExtractor
from scrapy.selector import HtmlXPathSelector
from scrapy.item import Item, Field
from scrapy.utils.response import get_base_url
from scrapy.utils.url import urljoin_rfc


class MySpider(CrawlSpider):

   name = 'crawl'
   allowed_domains = []
   start_urls = []

   def __init__(self):
      for line in open('domain.txt', 'r').readlines():
        self.allowed_domains.append(line)
        self.start_urls.append(line)
        rules = [Rule(SgmlLinkExtractor(allow=()), follow=True, callback='parse_item')]
        super(MySpider,self).__init__()


   def parse_item(self, response):
     sel = HtmlXPathSelector(response)
     links = sel.select('//a[contains(@href, "anything")]/@href').extract()
     items = []
     for link in links:
      item = AnythingItem()
      item['reference_link'] = response.url
      yield item
```

Update 0: I forgot to add colon after init function. Sorry. But still it doesn't work

Comment: `def __init__(self)` isn't valid Python. You need a colon after the function name.

Answer (score 1):

you forgot the colon (`:`) mark after the function definition to start a new block.

```
 def __init__(self):
```

A `SyntaxError` is an indication that the line of code you've written fails to parse by the Python interpreter. It simply means it's not a valid line of code.

Comment: It says closing spider.

Answer (score 0):

First, this code really works??
It should not work since you are doing `start_urls = ['http://www.apple.com\n']`, what is not a valid link. You should remove the newline character from the end of the line.

Second, are you sure domain.txt contains `apple.com`?
If so, scrapy should complain there is no scheme in the url.

You probably have `http://www.apple.com`. In this case, you are doing that:

```
allowed_domains = ['http://www.apple.com']
start_urls = ['http://www.apple.com']
```

And you want that:

```
allowed_domains = ['apple.com']
start_urls = ['http://www.apple.com']
```